# How to configure a fixed user ID on an NFS server?

Tags: osx, nfs

I'd like my NFS server to always use the same user ID to own the files, whatever user ID is used on the client.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: What NFS server are you running? On what unix variant?

Comment: @Gilles OSX Lion's built-in NFS server

Answer (score 4):

Put `-mapall=user` into your `exports` file.

See [`man exports`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/exports.5.html) for details

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, look at the [User ID mapping](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) section in the exports manpage.

Basically you want this in the exports line: `all_squash anonuid=whatever anongid=whatever`

If you're not on linux but on BSD, do what Chris S said.